# Simulink not receiving UDP messages

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, udp, simulink

I am using python to send messages to simulink however it isn't working

Python code

```
import socket
import time
from datetime import datetime

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind(("127.0.0.1", 12345))

for i in range(1000):
     message = bytes(str(1), encoding='utf-8')
     print("Sent")
     sock.sendto(message, ("127.0.0.1", 12345))
     print("--------------------------")
     time.sleep(0.001)
```

UDP receive block I'm using

[image]

So what I'm doing is running Simulink first to get ready to receive, then pummel it with 1000 python messages but none of them are being received!

Can someone shed some light on this matter please?

Comment: Try changing "bind" to "connect" in your python side. As noted in your other post, it looks like simulink is setting up a server socket, meaning python should set up the client socket. Do you have a reason why you need python to set the server here?

Comment: Ok thanks mate I will try that, yes I have to use python as the server. It's for synchronising events that occur from python.

Comment: Why can't that be done as a client?

Answer (score 0):

changing from bind to connect worked for me (win10 python 3.7 matlab2021b)

Comment: Question already answered with the exactly same solution in comments